# Automatically starting Service: pass data to Activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm already asked the question: [Pass data from Service to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492063/pass-data-from-service-to-activity/12494069#comment16813420_12494069)

How can I put `data` to SQLite storage 
and then get this value in my Activity? 
(database is already exists).

Comment: Find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728

Sample project is here http://sdrv.ms/N857Wn